# Can't make emacs to load the correct virtualenv

Tags: emacs

I wan't to compile python project in emacs. This project is running in a `virtualenvwrapper` environment. So i found a emacs plugin called `virtualenvwrapper` and use `M-x work-on` to choose virtualenv. After i have done this, the python interpreter and shell has been set to the correct python env, but when i compile emacs with `M-x compile`, it still can't found all the packages installed in python env.

I found this issue may be caused by `zsh`. After i change the default shell to `bash` in terminal. virtualenv works fine. Is it a bug of zsh or i haven't configured zsh with the right way.